# Using unnest in multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, array

I have an array column containing information like

```
{a,b,c,a} 
{a,b,a,b}
{b,a,a,b}
```

I want to run unnest on this array column, get the occurence of of each character.

```
a 2
b 1
c 1
a 2
b 2
b 2
a 2
```

I run the following query which works when considered for one row:

```
SELECT i, count(*) AS count
FROM   unnest(array::text[]) i
GROUP  BY i
ORDER  BY i;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the query below;

```
SELECT
  unnest(i),
  count(*)
FROM (
  VALUES 
    ('{a,b,c,a}'::text[]), 
    ('{a,b,a,b}'), 
    ('{b,a,a,b}')
) AS t(i)
GROUP BY 1, i   -- group by column value, you can use any unique field here
ORDER BY i
```